# Does g++ linker optimizes unused libraries out when creating shared libraries?

Tags: linux, g++, clang++

I have an object file and I want to create a shared library, `libA.so`, out of it and link it to another shared library, `libB.so`. The source file contains a single class and does not have any dependencies on `libB.so`.

I would create `libA.so` using either `clang++` or `g++`:

1. `clang++ -shared -L/PATH/TO/LIBB -Wl,-soname=libA.so -o main.so main.o -lB`
2. `g++ -shared -L/PATH/TO/LIBB -Wl,-soname=libA.so -o main.so main.o -lB`

Using `objdump` or `readelf` I can see that my library is listed in the first case (`clang`), **but** not in the second case (`g++`). Any ideas why?

**Example**

`C++` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Tain {
public:
  void test() {
    std::cout << "YES";
  }
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
  Tain t;
  t.test();
}
```

Result of `readelf -a main.so | grep -i needed`:

1. `g++ -shared -L/PATH/TO/BOOST -lboost_log -Wl,-soname=main.so -o main.so main.cpp`:

   0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]

   0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
2. `clang++-3.5 -shared -L/PATH/TO/BOOST -lboost_log -Wl,-soname=main.so -o main.so main.cpp`:

   0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_log.so.1.56.0]

   0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]

   0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]

   0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]

   0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]

Comment: Try the --as-needed ld option.

Comment: @n.m. no luck: `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--as-needed’`

Comment: This ia not a g++ option, this is a linker option. If you want to pass it to g++, you need `-Wl,--as-needed`.

Comment: @n.m. my bad, but still no luck. Strange thing is if I use some other classes from the shared library and make some extra calls, the library is listed again in `objdump` output.

Comment: It is listed but still I get a segmentation fault when trying to access some of the classes. This problem is not happening with clang.

Comment: Sorry my bad. --as-needed is the default with g++, not with clang. Your segmentation fault problem is probably unrelated.

Comment: @n.m. I am giving up :) thanks for taking time in investing the problem!